# Perl syntax (replacing 'defined(@array')

Tags: perl

Let me start by saying I haven't programmed in Perl in a LONG time.

Currently trying to get some older code to work that relies on `defined` with an array.

Code (abridged):

```
# defined outside the file-reading block
my %refPRE;

# line from a file
@c = split();


if (defined @{$refPRE{$c[0]}})
{
    # do stuff
}
```

Now this won't run like this because of the following error:

`Can't use 'defined(@array)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)`

Fine, but if I removed the `defined` then I get the following error:

`Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference`.

I can see what it's trying to do (if `$c[0]` is in the `$refPRE` then do this, else do something else) but I'm not familiar enough with Perl to figure out what the right way to get this to work is. Hoping this is trivial for someone.

Comment: Try: `if (exists $refPRE{$c[0]} and (ref $refPRE{$c[0]} eq "ARRAY") and @{$refPRE{$c[0]}})`

Comment: What you are trying to check for?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your second error `$refPRE{$c[0]}` can be undefined so `@{ ... }` is failing. You can fix this using the *undef or* opperator `//` like this.

```
if (@{ $refPRE{$c[0]} // [] }) { ... }
```

This checks if `$refPRE{$c[0]}` is defined and if not returns an empty anonymous array. An empty array is false in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently posting here is all the catalyst I needed...

Switching `if (defined @{$refPRE{$c[0]}})` to `if ($refPRE{$c[0]})` was sufficient to work! Hopefully this helps someone else who searching for this (specific) problem...

Comment: Rubber duck! :D

Answer (score 3):

> Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference.

This is saying that `$refPRE{ $c[0] }` is returning `undef`, and you cannot dereference `undef` as an array.

```
@{ undef } # will error
```

You don't need to deref this at all. If it returns `undef`, it's *false*. If it returns anything else, that will (likely) be *true*.

```
if ( $refPRE{$c[0]} )
{
   my $foo = @{ $refPRE{$c[0]} };
    # do stuff
}
```